# Programatically get category detail by multiple store view ids

Tags: admin, multistore, programmatically

I am working on one website multi store functionality. I am having store view ids in my array, i want to get all categories by store view id arrays.

Comment: are you want particulat once store_view category ids or multil store view categories list?

Comment: I want all active child categories list by store view ids.

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);


print_r($categories->getAllIds());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can click refer following code..

```
<?php
  require_once("app/Mage.php");
  Mage::app('default');
  Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
  try
  {
    $entityType = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId();
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType);
    $allSet = array();
    foreach($collection as $coll)
    {
      $attributeSet['name'] = $coll->getAttributeSetName();
      $attributeSet['id'] = $coll->getAttributeSetId();
      $allSet[] = $attributeSet;
    }
    Mage::log($allSet,1,'allSet.log');//make sure you have enabled log fron backend
    print_r($allSet);
    $attributeType = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY);
    $attributeCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setEntityTypeFilter($attributeType);
    $allAttributes = array();
    foreach($attributeCollection as $coll)
    {
        Mage::log($coll,1,'coll.log');
        $attribute['name'] = $coll->getAttributeCode();
        $attribute['id'] = $coll->getAttributeId();
        $allAttributes[] = $attribute;
    }
    Mage::log($allAttributes,1,'allAttributes.log');//make sure you have enabled log fron backend
    print_r($allAttributes);
  }catch(Exception $e){
  echo $e;
  }
?>
```